# 'Parent doesn't match' repeated error in xml file in Android Studio (v 2.1.1; SDK v23)

Tags: android

I'm using Android Studio version 2.1.1 with SDK version 23 and am attempting to build a Map Activity for my app but I'm faced with this:

[image]

What should I do? It's a university project.

P.S. This is only when I try a Map Activity.

Comment: can you please share your App build file

Comment: obvioulsy sdk used in project is not compatible(too low) for used libray

Answer (score 0):

Your compile SDK version must match the support library's major version.

Since you are using version 23 of the support library, you need to compile against version 23 of the Android SDK.

In your Build.gradle change

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
```

ckeck your build.gradle targetversion 23

```
android {

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
...
}
```

Comment: Hi, I checked my build.gradle file is already set to ' compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0' .

Comment: can you add your buld gridel?

Comment: The file doesn't fit in the comments section. Is there any way I can send it to you? I can neither attach a picture here nor the text. I tried.

Comment: android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "apps.vriddhi.com.emergency"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }